# Game Center Multiplayer Sandbox doesn't connect to players when invited

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center, multiplayer

I've got a GKMatchmakerViewController which works fine when auto-matching.  But when inviting players, it doesn't work.

Specifically, what happens is that the inviter is immediately connected to the invited player, but the invited player never connects to the inviter player.

For the following code:

```
[match expectedPlayerCount]
[match playerIDs]
```

The values on the inviter side are 0 and an array with the connected player's ID.  The values on the other side are 0 and an empty array.

What's the deal?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3325/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-22) is a great tutorial regarding `GKMatchMakerViewController`, which goes over how to invite other players. (This part is towards the bottom of the page.) Hope that Helps.

Comment: And if I were confused on how to get invitations to appear, that would be helpful.  But that's not the problem.  The GKMatchmakerViewController finishes, and returns a valid GKMatch, as mentioned in the question.  The error lies thereafter.